# ImageView with wrap_content height shows very skinny / cropped photo instead of full height

Tags: android, xml

I have a screen where the user can read an article (with large photo at the top.

It's general structure is:

```
LinearLayout -> ScrollView -> LinearLayout -> ImageViews,TextViews...etc
```

The ImageView I'm having problems with is the large image at the top (below the Article's title, but above it's text:

```
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/article_photo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/super_light_gray"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:contentDescription="@string/articlePhoto"
            android:cropToPadding="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:padding="1dp"/>
```

The problem is, **the photos appear, but are cropped vertically A LOT** so that even vertical-oriented photos show up very skinny and wide.  I assumed that "wrap_content" should make it the full height of the photo...  but I'm obviously wrong :)

How can I make the photo show up full width (already working), but also full height?

I'm using the UniversalImageLoader to load the images:

```
        if(lrgPhoto != null && !lrgPhoto.filepath.equals(""))
        {
            imageLoader.displayImage(
                "http://img.mysite.com/processes/resize_android.php?image=" + lrgPhoto.filepath + "&size=640&quality=90",
                imageView,
                imgDisplayOptions
                );
            imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //show photo
        }
        else
        {
            imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE); //hide photo
            imageView.invalidate();
        }
```

**Edit:**

If I change 'scaleType' to 'fitXY', then the image shows correct dimensions without being cropped, but then it's not full-width.  Is there a way I can have both full-width AND not-cropped strangely?

It appears the "crop" is because it's using the original height of the image for the height, but it's enlarging the image to fit full-width...

Comment: I think you want wrap_content for both width and height

Comment: @raydowe - but I want the width to be the width of the screen.

Comment: @raydowe - though - that does make it so they don't get cropped strangely - so - that's a good start...but then they're not full width. :/

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part of the question

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Add this to the imageview xml:

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Comment: Wow, this should be the real answer. I can't believe this isn't on by default.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

to

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought this was straightforward, but it looks like it might not be possible with xml layout alone:

[ImageView - have height match width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798392/imageview-have-height-match-width)

Comment: I agree that it may not be possible w /xml alone, but I also don't just want them to be fixed-width square images like the link provided.

Comment: Right, I was just linking to show the answers that all say it's not possible in XML. Since you're going to be writing java code, if you can get the original image dimensions it should be relatively straight forward to find the new, full size width and apply the same ratio to the height.