# How can I create layout with equal width and height for CalendarView?

Tags: android, layout, calendarview

How can I create layout with equal width and height for `CalendarView`? Answers to the same question for `ImageView` don't work with `CalendarView`:

[ImageView - have height match width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798392/imageview-have-height-match-width)

Current layout:

```
    <CalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calendarView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to get width of the device at runtime. And set through layout params like new LayoutParams(width_of_device , width_of_device) and apply layout params. So you can set equal width and height of calendar view.